# BIND zone also-notify syntax

Tags: bind

Given the following my BIND 9 is not able to start.

```
acl ns2 { 192.168.10.50; };
zone "10.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        also-notify { ns2 port 53; };
        type master;
        file "192.168.10.db";
};
```

It's writing the following to the /var/log/messages file.

```
[root@dev bind]# tail /var/log/messages
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: found 4 CPUs, using 4 worker threads
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: using 4 UDP listeners per interface
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: using up to 4096 sockets
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: /etc/named.conf:18: missing ';' before 'port'
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: /etc/named.conf:18: missing ';' before '53'
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: /etc/named.conf:23: missing ';' before 'port'
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: /etc/named.conf:23: missing ';' before '53'
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: loading configuration: failure
Jan 25 18:41:05 dev named[22863]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

This is strange because per their guide [here](http://www.bind9.net/manual/bind/9.3.2/Bv9ARM.ch06.html), the correct statement syntax is

```
[ also-notify { ip_addr [port ip_port] ; [ ip_addr [port ip_port] ; ... ] }; ]
```

Comment: And `ns2` is not an IP address.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks but I actually have an acl line above that to specify the IP address for ns2.  Just edited my post to include that acl line.  Can you have a look again?

Comment: Try with an IP, not an ACL. Also be aware that the syntax for `also-notify` changed with Bind 9.9. Which one are you using exactly?

Comment: @Marki I'm using 9.9.4-P2.  Are you saying the acl line is no longer supported in 9.9.4-P2?

Comment: I'm saying the format for `also-notify` changed. http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/xfer.html#also-notify

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed it by doing the following...
If anyone knows why we now have both masters and acl, rather than just acl, please enlighten me.

```
acl ns2 { 192.168.10.50; };
masters ns2 { 192.168.10.50 port 53; };

options {
        allow-query { any; };
        allow-recursion { localnets; };
        allow-transfer { ns2; };
        directory "/var/named";
        dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        pid-file "/var/run/named.pid";
};

zone "10.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        also-notify { ns2; };
        type master;
        file "192.168.10.db";
};
```

Comment: 1) You can (should) accept your own answer, too. 2) In your answer don't make a new question, instead of it formulate as a new question.

Comment: @user192702 .... This is not working if i add segment instead of IP in acl ns2... any idea why so ?
I am not finding any way of having segments (instead of IPs) in "also-notify" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your zone as follow:

```
zone "10.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        also-notify { 192.168.10.50; };
        type master;
        file "192.168.10.db";
};
```

If the slave is running on another port rather than 53, you can specify if changing the allow-notify as follow:

```
also-notify { 192.168.10.50 port xxx; };
```

Unless port is specified, bind send the notification to port 53.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to put:

masters "acl-name" { 
 ip1;
 ip2;
 ip3;
 etc;}

and then call it after with also-notify { acl-name;}; sentence.

Comment: Any idea how to have segments instead of IP ?